# Show in terminal strings that are saved in a log.file while running the python application

Tags: python

I have a python application in which I have developed a short function to print useful messages in a file

```
#To create and config logger
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file,
                   format='%(asctime)s%(message)s',
                   filemode='a'
                   )
#To create the object
logger=logging.getLogger()
#To set the threshold of logger to DEBUG
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
def log_messages(text):
    '''
    To be called in other scripts to record
    INFO/WARNING/ERROR messages 
    '''
    logging.info(text)
```

I would like also to show this info while the application is running. How can I do this?

Comment: just see what `logging.setLevel` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different handlers for your logging (a handler for writing to file, and a handler for writing to the console)

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s%(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(log_file),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ]
)
```

Comment: If this application is run many times. The information, filemode=a will remain even if now does not recognize it now with your siggestion?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking if FileHandler will append to the log file?